# how to make empty first row of selected rows in mysql database table

Tags: mysql

**Question:**

How to make empty or null of first row of selected rows in MySQL database table.

**NOTE:**

if first row having value also should make empty or null while selecting from mysql database table.

**Sample Table**

```
ID     Name       Age
1      Ramkumar   24
2      Dinesh     26
3      Gupta      25
```

**Expected Table Format While Selecting Table**

```
ID     Name       Age
1      0          24
2      Dinesh     26
3      Gupta      25
```

**NOTE:**
Above i am expecting 0 instead of Ramkumar while selecting

Comment: Show some sample records as *existing* and *expected* records.

Comment: plz check my post, i made sample table

Comment: And on those existing records, what is the expected pattern of records. Show them too.

Comment: Your question should be like *I have this table with sample records* and *I am expecting following pattern of records*. Rules are blah, blah ....

Comment: plz check my post, i have updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT ID ,
       CASE WHEN row_number = 1 Then '0' ELSE Name END AS Name , 
       Age 
FROM 
(
SELECT  l.ID AS ID, 
        l.Name AS Name, 
        l.Age AS Age,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    Tabe1 l
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
) AS T
```

OR:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN row_number = 1 Then NULL ELSE ID END AS ID ,
       CASE WHEN row_number = 1 Then NULL ELSE Name END AS Name , 
       CASE WHEN row_number = 1 Then NULL ELSE Age END AS Age 
FROM 
(
SELECT  l.ID AS ID, 
        l.Name AS Name, 
        l.Age AS Age,
        @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number
FROM    Tabe1 l
JOIN    (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
) AS T
```

Comment: The derived table will slow performance. This can be done without the inline view. Also, if an ORDER BY is added on the outer query, the row from T that has row_number=1 may not be the "first" row.

Comment: i am getting error boss, #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 11

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
SELECT t.id
     , IF(@first_row = 1, @first_row := NULL, t.name) AS name
     , t.age
  FROM mytable t
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT @first_row := 1 AS first_row) fr
 ORDER BY t.name ASC
```

The inline view (derived table) aliased as fr gets run first, and it has a side effect of initializing a user variable `@first_row` to a value of 1.

To do the same thing on multiple columns, then do the assignment of NULL to `@first_row` variable in only in the last expression it's referenced in. Before that, return literal NULL. Or, use multiple user variables, one for each column to be replaced.

```
SELECT t.id
     , IF(@first_row = 1, 0, t.name) AS name
     , IF(@first_row = 1, @first_row := NULL, t.age) AS age
  FROM mytable t
 CROSS
  JOIN (SELECT @first_row := 1 AS first_row) fr
 ORDER BY t.id DESC
```

**NOTE:** This behavior is specific to MySQL, and it's not guaranteed; it could change in a future release.